# Azure Signalr - Server connections increasing trough time

Tags: azure, .net-core, signalr, azure-signalr

I have a notitifactions project that uses SignalR to push notifications to an Angular client. What I noticed is that when I deploy my app, I define the server connections count as 5 (default) but trough time I can see that the server connections are increasing and I don't know why this is happening.

You can see in this picture my server and client connections in 30 days. It starts with 5 when I deploy the app and today it has 19 and max was 29.

[image: Azure SignalR Connections]

Is this expected behavior or I doing something wrong in my hub?

My configuration for SignalR:

```js
"AzureSignalROptions": {
    "ConnectionString": "(...)",
    "ClientTimeoutInterval": 3600,
    "HandshakeTimeout": 30,
    "KeepAliveInterval": 15,
    "EnableDetailedErrors": false,
    "MaximumReceiveMessageSize": 32000,
    "StreamBufferCapacity": 10,
    "SupportedProtocols": null,
    "ServerConnectionCount": 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected.

> During the lifetime of the application server, the service and the application server keep sync connection status and make adjustment to server connections for better performance and service stability. So you might see server connection number changes from time to time.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-concept-messages-and-connections#how-connections-are-counted

Comment: Thank you, I miss this section of the documentation. Now it is clear!